# Capture mouseup event outside of browser/window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Right now I'm stopping drag events on mouse up, like so:

```
$(document).mouseup(_onMouseUp);
```

However I need to capture mouse up events when the mouse leaves the browser window, similar to `releaseOutside` in Flash.

Is this possible in JS?

Comment: Keyboard/mouse events only work when the browser is focused (Unless you're IE: http://spider.io/blog/2012/12/internet-explorer-data-leakage/).  This would be a huge security hole.

Comment: It is possible to detect that the document lost focus, as I've detailed below in my answer.  This will likely accomplish what the OP wants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't detect a mouseup or mousedown event outside of the browser window, but I think what you are trying to do is cancel a drag or drop when the user clicks off the browser window.  You *can* accomplish that, by reacting to the browser window losing focus, e.g.:

```
$(window).on("blur", function(e) {
    // Cancel my drag and drop here
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("blur", function(e) {
    // Cancel my drag and drop here
});
```

This covers you for mouse clicks outside the browser window, and also things like Windows Alt+Tab task switching.

Comment: I guess it should be `window` instead of `document`, see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

Comment: I've tested `document` in all 5 major browsers and on several types of devices.  However, feel free to use `window`, that also works.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible to capture mouseup events outside the browser window. Just call [Element.setCapture()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture) inside mousedown callback.

Remember to call [document.releaseCapture()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/releaseCapture) on mouseup also.

```
elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    ...
    elem.setCapture();
});
elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    ...
    document.releaseCapture();
});
```

Comment: FYI Element.setCapture() is not supported in Chrome yet (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246536)

Comment: Yes, but doesn't Chrome capture the mouse by default?

Comment: I don't know, but even if it did, elem.setCapture() currently throws an exception in Chrome, so some care is still necessary.

Comment: `releaseCapture` is not necessary unless you want to release capture *before* `mouseup`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture

Comment: MDN recommends [setPointerCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture) instead since it has wider browser support. It works pretty much the same, but you have to pass it a pointer ID. You can get the pointer ID from the `pointerdown` event, which should be used in place of `mousedown`. I guess the pointer ID might be for multi-touch interfaces - it always seems to be 1 from my testing.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Chrome. I drag out an image, but when I leave it on the desktop, the event is not fired.

Answer (score 9):

You can capture mouseup events outside the browser window in every major browser: Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

You just need to **attach the listener to the 'window' object**, like this:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseup', 
                         () => console.log('mouse up captured outside the window'));
```

https://codepen.io/fredrikborgstrom/pen/vRBaZw

or in your case, using jQuery, it would be:

```
$(window).mouseup(_onMouseUp);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Chrome. I drag out an image, but when I leave it on the desktop, the event is not fired.

Comment: @YTG If you're doing a drag and drop, then do this:
window.addEventListener("dragend", () => console.log('drag end event caught'));
This will work if dropping outside the browser window.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to capture mouse up event outside of browser window like below:

```
elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    ...
    elem.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
});
elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    ...
    elem.releasePointerCapture(e.pointerId);
});
```

References:
[setPointerCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture)
[releasePointerCapture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/releasePointerCapture)

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Chrome. I drag out an image, but when I leave it on the desktop, the event is not fired.

Comment: I believe you have to use the events pointerdown, pointermove, and pointerup instead of mousedown, mouseup, etc., to be able to get the pointerId. They look as if they can be used interchangeably: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899775/pointerdown-vs-onclick-what-is-the-difference