# Is there a way to detect if user is active when chrome window is not in focus?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create extension that resets the timer when the user is not active. The problem that i am having is that when i switch to other application none of the listeners trigger. Is there a way to make listeners work in the background while the chrome window is out of focus and i am working in other application?

Here are the listeners that i am using

```
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);
```

If not what could be other way to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture mouseup event outside of browser/window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407869/capture-mouseup-event-outside-of-browser-window)

Comment: No, but you can write a separate utility and use it in your extension via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: @wOxxOm by separate utility could you give and example, do you mean like build small windows user detection app in like c# that uses this nativeMessaging API ?

Comment: I don't have an example so try looking for one. And yes, you've guessed right.