# pointerdown vs onclick: what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

What is the difference between the `onpointerdown` and `onclick` event handlers?

Are there any practical differences? Are the events not propagated the same up the DOM tree? Are there some devices that only respond to one of these events?

I initially assumed that it is only `pointerdown` that is triggered in touch devices or with a pen, but `onclick` seems to be triggered as well.

Comment: There are many differences.  Here is an example where I used onpointerdown (and other related onpointer* methods) to capture multiple simultaneous pointers (single mouse or multiple simultaneous touches) on multiple elements at the same time. 
 https://codepen.io/sassano/pen/JjzzQKo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Are there any practical differences?

> Yes there are.

`pointerDown` it's actually equivalent to `onMouseDown` but the main difference is that `mouseDown` only sends to an `Element` but `pointerDown` can be sent to `Document`, `Window`, and `Element`.

2. What is the difference between the `onpointerdown` and `onclick` event handlers?

- `pointerDown` can captures the right/left/middle clicks.
- `onClick` only captures the left click.

Live Example:

> The example will make it clearer.

https://codepen.io/nawafscript/pen/WNEyRyO

Comment: Hey Nawaf, 

The above looks like it should read "onClick only captures the left click."

Answer (score 8):

To add to Nawaf answer:
The point in time when the evenhandlers are fired is also different (at least when using mouse).

- onPointerDown fires when the mouse button is pressed down
- onClick waits for press AND release of the mouse button.