# How to reset `top`, `left`, `transition` attributes using a css class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below is meant for simulating a drag and drop effect. I'm manually changing the styles both on `mousedown` and `mouseup` events using `Object.assign(target.style, ...)`. If I replace the assigment statements with `.dragging` class that contains the `mousedown` styles, followed by removing that class on `mouseup`, the associated `left` and `top` attributes set in `mouseup` stay after removing the `.dragging` class.

Here's the working version:

```js
(function() {
    let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
    let offsetX;
    let offsetY;
    targets.forEach((target) => {
        target.isMouseDown = false;
        target.initialOffsetLeft = target.offsetLeft;
        target.initialOffsetTop = target.offsetTop;
        target.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            if (e.buttons === 1) {
                Object.assign(target.style, {
                    transition: null,
                    zIndex: 10000,
                    position: 'relative'
                });
                target.isMouseDown = true;
                offsetX = target.initialOffsetLeft + e.offsetX;
                offsetY = target.initialOffsetTop + e.offsetY;
            }
        });
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            target.isMouseDown = false;
            Object.assign(target.style, {
                transition: 'all 0.5s ease',
                zIndex: null,
                left:  '0',
                top: '0'
            });
        });
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (target.isMouseDown) {
                target.style.left = e.pageX - offsetX + 'px';
                target.style.top = e.pageY - offsetY + 'px';
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.draggable {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  cursor: grab;
  flex-grow: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #6c757d;
}

.my-card-group {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card group">
  <div class="my-card-group">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
      </div>
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
      </div>
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I do to replace the `Object.assign(...)` statements with `.dragging` class:

```js
(function() {
    let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
    let offsetX;
    let offsetY;
    targets.forEach((target) => {
        target.isMouseDown = false;
        target.initialOffsetLeft = target.offsetLeft;
        target.initialOffsetTop = target.offsetTop;
        target.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            if (e.buttons === 1) {
                target.classList.add('dragging')  // replaced with this
                target.isMouseDown = true;
                offsetX = target.initialOffsetLeft + e.offsetX;
                offsetY = target.initialOffsetTop + e.offsetY;
            }
        });
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            target.isMouseDown = false;
            target.classList.remove('dragging') // replaced with this
        });
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (target.isMouseDown) {
                target.style.left = e.pageX - offsetX + 'px';
                target.style.top = e.pageY - offsetY + 'px';
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

```css
 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.draggable {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 11px 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    cursor: grab;
    flex-grow: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #6c757d;
    transition: all 0.5s ease; /*added this*/
    z-index: unset; /*added this*/
    left: 0; /*added this*/
    top: 0 /*added this*/
}

.dragging { /*added this*/
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0s;
}

.my-card-group {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #6c757d;
}
```

```html
 
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card group">
  <div class="my-card-group">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
      </div>
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
      </div>
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This breaks how the dragging works because `left` and `top` as well as `transition` attributes persist after `.dragging` is removed, and the next time any of the `.draggable` is dragged, it starts where its previous drag ended and with a transition delay set by `.dragging`. Is there a way to achieve the initial behavior using a similar approach?

Comment: During the mouseup event, just add `target.style.left = target.style.top = "";`

Comment: this is similar to what I was doing initially using `Object.assign(...)`. Same goes for the transition delay.

Comment: Try to reset by removing the draggable class from your html element

Comment: You can use the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event) event handler to remove the values after it ended they can be removed by setting it to `""`. Which is different than setting it to 0.

Comment: @Roland This way, all `.draggable` will lose their initial styling and it doesn't even fix the problem. The same side effects happen afterwards.

Comment: @Christopher so, this can't be done using a css class alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code comments.

```js
(function() {
  let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
  targets.forEach((target) => {
    let offsetX;
    let offsetY;
    target.isMouseDown = false;
    target.initialOffsetLeft = target.offsetLeft;
    target.initialOffsetTop = target.offsetTop;
    target.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      if (e.button == 0) {
        // moved preventDefault, to not trigger on rclick or auxclick
        e.preventDefault();
        // clean start, it can appear that resetting is still present,
        // during the animation when you regrab it within the animation duration
        target.classList.remove("resetting");
        target.style.left = target.style.top = "0px";
        
        target.classList.add('dragging') // replaced with this
        target.isMouseDown = true;
        offsetX = target.initialOffsetLeft + e.offsetX;
        offsetY = target.initialOffsetTop + e.offsetY;
      }
    });
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
      // added check if the targets mouse is down
      // this is required as you listen on the whole document
      // also it won't trigger anymore if right mouseup is fired
      if (target.isMouseDown && e.button == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        target.isMouseDown = false;
        target.classList.remove('dragging');

        // adds the "move back" animation from the first example
        target.classList.add("resetting");

        // removes everything again that was when the transition effect ended
        target.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
          Object.assign(target.style, { top: "", left: "" });
          target.classList.remove("resetting");
        }, { once: true });
      }
    });
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      // moved preventDefault() inside the condition to prevent unwanted behavior on other scripts, as you listen on the whole document
      if (target.isMouseDown) {
        e.preventDefault();  
        target.style.left = e.pageX - offsetX + 'px';
        target.style.top = e.pageY - offsetY + 'px';
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.draggable {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 11px 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    cursor: grab;
    flex-grow: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #6c757d;
}
/* This removes the animation during dragging */
.draggable:not(.dragging) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
/* this allows the animation to play from the current position back to 0,0 */
.draggable.resetting {
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0px!important;
    left: 0px!important;
    position: relative;
}
.draggable.dragging {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
}

.my-card-group {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card group">
  <div class="my-card-group">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
      </div>
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
      </div>
      <div class="draggable">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second and third `.draggable` are broken

Comment: Please clearify what you are doing. I can't confirm it.

Comment: drag any of them multiple times toward the bottom, they will stay there.

Comment: If you release the mousebutton "outside" of the snippet, this can break it. If you release it inside the snippet preview, everything works as expected. Try running the snippet in Full Page View.

Comment: the same thing happens in full view when dragged out of the window, but I just noticed it does the same thing in the initial snippet, not sure why though.

Comment: With [document.setCapture() and document.releaseCapture()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35236929/10304804) you can capture the mouse inside the window. The browser window itself, doesn't get an event if the mouseup is fired outside of the window.